# RESTeasy and the @MultipartForm , server and client

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-client, spring-jersey

Walking through the [RESTEasy Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.4.0.Final/userguide/html_single/) 4.4.0-final from jboss.
Having the [examples](https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy-examples) to guide be as well.

Wanting to create a small service where you post a binary-file with some metadata. In this particular case I would like to post a file + 'the owner of that file'.

---

In my **first** effort I am using the following construct (1st-attempt-server).

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream is,
      @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
  Map<String, String> map = fileDetail.getParameters();
}
```

I am able to save the file, but the only information I can get from 'fileDetail' is the filename.
The client ('1st-attempt-client')  calling '1st-attempt-server' looks like this:

```
public void uploadFile() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

   String endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/Uploadv03/rest/upload"; 
   String filePath = "/tmp/testimage.jpg";
   File file = new File(filePath);
   FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file,ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY);

   MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
   builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
   builder.addPart("file", fileBody);
   String owner="me-myself";
   builder.addTextBody("owner", owner, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
   HttpEntity entity = builder.build();

   HttpPost request = new HttpPost(endpoint);
   request.setEntity(entity);
   HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
   try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("statuscode "+statusCode);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Looking into the map in the server, that map only gives me 2-key-pairs and those are (name=file and filename=testimage.jpg) -it seems that I cannot fetch the 'owner'-attribute.

---

In my **second** effort I am using the following construct (2nd-attempt-server). I am sure that I have used this construct before, couple of years ago.

```
 @POST
 @Path("/load")
 @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
 public Response external(@MultipartForm FileUploadForm form) throws IOException {
        logger.info("the 'load'-endpoint ");
 }
```

the supporting file:FileuploadForm looks like this (with getters/setters)

```
public class FileUploadForm implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FileUploadForm() {
    }

    @FormParam("selectedFile")
    @PartType("application/octet-stream")
    private byte[] file;

    @FormParam("owner")
    private String owner;

    getters/setters
}
```

The client ('2nd-attempt-client')  calling '2nd-attempt-server' looks like this:

```
private void post() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

     System.out.println("PostClient2\n");  
     String endpoint = "http://localhost:8080/Uploadv03/rest/upload"; 
     String owner = "me-myself";
     String filename = "naming-the-file";

     String filePath = "/tmp/testimage.jpg"
     File file = new File(filePath);
     FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

     DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost uploadFile = new HttpPost(URL);

     MultipartEntityBuilder builder= MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
     builder.addTextBody("owner", owner, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
     builder.addBinaryBody("file", inputStream);
     HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
     uploadFile.setEntity(multipart);

     HttpResponse response = null;
     try {
          response = httpClient.execute(uploadFile);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Unable to make connection");
        }
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Statuscode "+statusCode);
    }
```

Now I am getting [HTTPS status 415](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) as a response.

The second server, what is lacking in the client-side code?
It does not seem to matter if I change to this

```
 builder.addBinaryBody("selectedFile", inputStream);
```

I do like the second approach here using a POJO, I am deploying the code in Tomcat 8. Surely the jersey-code would be sufficient here, I have seen some other dependencies as well, but I would like this 'clean' example to work if that is feasible ( I do not find a simple example in the guide)

---

For the server-side code  I am using these jersey-dependencies (part of my pom.xml) and I am deplying the code in Tomcat 8.

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <jersey.version>1.19.4</jersey.version>
  <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>

    <!-- Works for Tomcat 8-->
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-multipart -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

          <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: what about passing the owner name as next parameter in controller method?

Comment: thank you for your time 'itwasntme'. specifically, in which of the solutions do you propose this 1or2 and how would your solution look like in the server respective and the client ?